# Django 2.2 compatibility with PostgreSQL

Tags: django, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm working on a Django app on a Linux server and found out the existing PostgreSQL isn't supported by Django. If Postgres is upgraded to the most recent version ([looks like v 12](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)), will it be compatible with Django 2.2 and psycopg2 version 2.8.5? Is there a "too new" version of Postgres that I should worry about for either Django or psycopg2?

I've tried to answer this question for myself using the relevant [Django docs](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SupportedDatabaseVersions) and [psycopg](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html#prerequisites) docs, and I think everything will be okay, but I haven't found a definitive answer. I just don't want to have to make the system administrator uninstall and reinstall and older version of Postgres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never seen a "too recent" version of PostgreSQL for Django - just the other way around. That's not to say there will never be a breaking change in PostgreSQL that will affect Django some day, but it hasn't in my 5 years of using Django.

I'm currently using Django 2.2 and 3 with PostgreSQL 10 and 12, and psycopg2 2.7 compiled, and 2.8 binary without issues across several projects.